# 642% CPU used along with GPU during training. Is it normal?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, nvidia

I have a PC configuration of

CPU: Intel Core i7 9700K @ 3.60 Ghz

GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX1060

When I train using tensorflow-gpu, both my CPU and GPU are used. Is this  normal behavior?

The usage stats as below from

`htop`

[image: htop])

`nvidia-smi`

[image: GPU]

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is normal because Tensorflow uses CPU for certain operations like data preproccessing. For more you can check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance_analysis#3_are_you_reaching_high_cpu_utilization). If you want to have a better insight about what utilizes your CPU, try the [Profiler](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler) tools suite.